# GCHelper raising exception

Tags: java

I am writing a program (called [Enchanting](http://enchanting.robotclub.ab.ca/), to let kids program LEGO Mindstorms NXT robots more easily) that has a front-end (based on [Scratch](http://scratch.mit.edu/), and written in Squeak Smalltalk) and a back-end (written in Java, using the [LeJOS NXJ](http://lejos.sourceforge.net/) framework).  Users drag and drop tiles to create code; it is converted to a java source file and then compiled.

I have included the 32-bit Apache Harmony JDK, because the [LeJOS framework requires a 32-bit JDK](http://lejos.sourceforge.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=2395#p11636), and because I could clearly redistribute it despite LeJOS offering a re-implementation of Java on an embedded computer.  Things work fine under Windows XP, and even under Windows 7 Starter, both of which are 32-bit OSes.

On Windows 7 (non-Starter, 64-bit), the backend fails.  I've finally determined that it is Harmony.

Here is the simplest command that produces the failure, `java -version`, and the output thereof (with the locale set to Greek -- but don't worry, almost all of the output is English):

```
Microsoft Windows [Έκδοση 6.1.7600]
Πνευματικά δικαιώματα (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. Με επιφύλαξη κάθε νόμιμου δικαιώματος.

C:\Users\USERNAME>cd "\Program Files\Enchanting\ThirdParty\harmony_jdk6\jre\bin"

C:\Program Files\Enchanting\ThirdParty\harmony_jdk6\jre\bin>java -version
Exception raised while initializing helper class org/apache/harmony/drlvm/gc_gen/GCHelper
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.

Signal reported: ABORT

Registers info is absent

Command line:
java  -version

Working directory:
C:\Program Files\Enchanting\ThirdParty\harmony_jdk6\jre\bin

Environment variables:
=::=::\
=C:=C:\Program Files\Enchanting\ThirdParty\harmony_jdk6\jre\bin
ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData
APPDATA=C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming
CLASSPATH=.;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip
CommonProgramFiles=C:\Program Files\Common Files
COMPUTERNAME=COMPUTERNAME
ComSpec=C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
FP_NO_HOST_CHECK=NO
HOMEDRIVE=C:
HOMEPATH=\Users\USERNAME
LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local
LOGONSERVER=\\COMPUTERNAME
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=2
NXJ_HOME=C:\Program Files\leJOS NXJ
OS=Windows_NT
Path=C:\Program Files\Enchanting\ThirdParty\harmony_jdk6\jre\bin\default;C:\Prog
ram Files\Enchanting\ThirdParty\harmony_jdk6\jre\bin\;C:\Program Files\ImageMagi
ck-6.7.4-Q16;C:\Program Files\leJOS NXJ\bin;C:\Program Files\PC Connectivity Sol
ution\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\sy
stem32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell
\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files\QuickTime\QTSystem\
;C:\Program Files\Pinnacle\Shared Files\;C:\Program Files\Pinnacle\Shared Files\
Filter\;C:\VXIPNP\WinNT\Bin
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=x86
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=x86 Family 15 Model 4 Stepping 3, GenuineIntel
PROCESSOR_LEVEL=15
PROCESSOR_REVISION=0403
ProgramData=C:\ProgramData
ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files
PROMPT=$P$G
PSModulePath=C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\
PUBLIC=C:\Users\Public
QTJAVA=C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip
SESSIONNAME=Console
SystemDrive=C:
SystemRoot=C:\Windows
TEMP=C:\Users\2FD9~1\AppData\Local\Temp
TMP=C:\Users\2FD9~1\AppData\Local\Temp
USERDOMAIN=COMPUTERNAME
USERNAME=USERNAME
USERPROFILE=C:\Users\USERNAME
VBOX_INSTALL_PATH=C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\
VXIPNPPATH=C:\VXIPNP\
windir=C:\Windows

Loaded modules:

c:\program files\enchanting\thirdparty\harmony_jdk6\jre\bin\java.exe:
        0x00400000:0x0040d000
c:\windows\system32\ntdll.dll:
        0x77d50000:0x77e8c000
c:\windows\system32\kernel32.dll:
        0x76c80000:0x76d54000
c:\windows\system32\kernelbase.dll:
        0x76100000:0x7614a000
c:\program files\enchanting\thirdparty\harmony_jdk6\jre\bin\hyprt.dll:
        0x01d80000:0x01d97000
c:\program files\enchanting\thirdparty\harmony_jdk6\jre\bin\hythr.dll:
        0x01db0000:0x01e08000
c:\program files\enchanting\thirdparty\harmony_jdk6\jre\bin\msvcr71.dll:
        0x01f10000:0x01f66000
c:\windows\system32\ws2_32.dll:
        0x77ee0000:0x77f15000
c:\windows\system32\msvcrt.dll:
        0x77c00000:0x77cac000
c:\windows\system32\rpcrt4.dll:
        0x76580000:0x76621000
c:\windows\system32\nsi.dll:
        0x76570000:0x76576000
c:\windows\system32\advapi32.dll:
        0x76e80000:0x76f20000
c:\windows\system32\sechost.dll:
        0x77ec0000:0x77ed9000
c:\program files\enchanting\thirdparty\harmony_jdk6\jre\bin\default\harmonyvm.dl
l:
        0x009a0000:0x00d27000
c:\program files\enchanting\thirdparty\harmony_jdk6\jre\bin\default\icuuc34.dll:

        0x01580000:0x01648000
c:\program files\enchanting\thirdparty\harmony_jdk6\jre\bin\default\icudt34.dll:

        0x01f70000:0x027e0000
c:\program files\enchanting\thirdparty\harmony_jdk6\jre\bin\default\ch.dll:
        0x00d30000:0x00fd0000
c:\windows\system32\user32.dll:
        0x76a80000:0x76b49000
c:\windows\system32\gdi32.dll:
        0x76e30000:0x76e7e000
c:\windows\system32\lpk.dll:
        0x76c70000:0x76c7a000
c:\windows\system32\usp10.dll:
        0x77cb0000:0x77d4d000
c:\windows\system32\dbghelp.dll:
        0x6ec60000:0x6ed4b000
c:\program files\enchanting\thirdparty\harmony_jdk6\jre\bin\hyzlib.dll:
        0x01e10000:0x01e22000
c:\program files\enchanting\thirdparty\harmony_jdk6\jre\bin\msvcp71.dll:
        0x01e90000:0x01f0b000
c:\windows\system32\psapi.dll:
        0x77eb0000:0x77eb5000
c:\windows\system32\userenv.dll:
        0x75500000:0x75517000
c:\windows\system32\profapi.dll:
        0x75ee0000:0x75eeb000
c:\windows\system32\imm32.dll:
        0x77e90000:0x77eaf000
c:\windows\system32\msctf.dll:
        0x76d60000:0x76e2c000
c:\windows\temp\logishrd\lvprcinj01.dll:
        0x00200000:0x0021b000
c:\windows\system32\sspicli.dll:
        0x75df0000:0x75e0b000
c:\program files\enchanting\thirdparty\harmony_jdk6\jre\bin\default\em.dll:
        0x003c0000:0x003e4000
c:\program files\enchanting\thirdparty\harmony_jdk6\jre\bin\default\jitrino.dll:

        0x01810000:0x01c93000
c:\program files\enchanting\thirdparty\harmony_jdk6\jre\bin\default\gc_gen_uncom
p.dll:
        0x00410000:0x0044d000
c:\program files\enchanting\thirdparty\harmony_jdk6\jre\bin\hynio.dll:
        0x001d0000:0x001d6000
c:\program files\enchanting\thirdparty\harmony_jdk6\jre\bin\default\vmi.dll:
        0x003f0000:0x003f6000
c:\program files\enchanting\thirdparty\harmony_jdk6\jre\bin\hyluni.dll:
        0x00450000:0x00473000
c:\windows\system32\iphlpapi.dll:
        0x73f20000:0x73f3c000
c:\windows\system32\winnsi.dll:
        0x73f10000:0x73f17000
c:\windows\system32\mswsock.dll:
        0x75920000:0x7595c000
c:\program files\enchanting\thirdparty\harmony_jdk6\jre\bin\hyarchive.dll:
        0x00480000:0x0048c000

No stack trace due to registers info absence

C:\Program Files\Enchanting\ThirdParty\harmony_jdk6\jre\bin>
```

When I run that same command on Windows 7 starter, java spits out a version number like it should, and everything is happy.

Any thoughts on what I can do to address this, or what the error message means?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try java -Xint -version and see if you can reproduce the problem?

Comment: It may be that you need the 64-bit version of the JDK.

Comment: @Amir, the results with -Xint were almost identical (it looks like only the line following 'Command line:' changed).  The -d32 flag is unrecognized.

Comment: You're running out of jre/bin.  Is there a harmony_jdk6/bin directory that you can run java out of?  If so, can you re-test and post the results?